# What effect does pressing a button group button have?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, buttongroup

I've read through Twitter bootstrap's documentation on [Button Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups). They look very pretty, but what effect, if any, is pressing one of the buttons supposed to have?

Comment: On its own, it's are just group of buttons. You do the callback implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What effect are you expect? 
Usually, I will use Jquery to catch the event of clicking one button. 
Just use them as normal buttons.

Comment: Ah - JavaScript callbacks, rather than making some sort of GET or POST?

Comment: If you use <form> and configure the button correctly, it will be a POST.